# UiTest not recording on Xcode 12, iOS 14.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing, simulator

I'm working on a small test Xcode project that I'm using to better understand and improve application testing practices. I didn't have any problem with the core functionalities tests, however I'm stuck on UI testing: when I try to record UI interactions, nothing happens. The recording button works properly and the application is correctly built and launched, but it seems like no input is catch. Is anyone experiencing the same issue or know what a possible workaround could be? Xcode version is 12.5 (12E262) and the simulator is running iOS 14.5.

[The functions stays empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyLb4.png)

Comment: I've had this problem intermittently on XCode when using SwiftUI. I don't have a fix I'm afraid, instead I've gone back to programmatically identifying UI elements to test.

Comment: Also having this problem and still haven’t found an resolution yet. Will Update if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Xcode 12.5
This is apple problem and it's allready fixed in version 12.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I downloaded Xcode 12.4, and it works well. You guys can try and using both Xcode versions. I hope Apple engineers will fix to next version